# Change value of abstract class in abstract repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Im having a super class like the following:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id = "";

    protected String firstname = "";

    protected String lastname = "";

    protected Address address = null;

    // getter setter
```

As you can see im using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` ans the `InheritanceType` and I want to keep it like that.

Now I got two subclasses inheriting from `Base`

```
@Entity
public class Consulter extends Base {
    // other fields
} 

@Entity
public class Customer extends Base {
    // other fields
}
```

When I now create a repository like the following:

```
public interface Base_Repository extends JpaRepository<Base, Long> {

}
```

Will jpa be able to return the correct Object from the database when I provide the id of a concrete type? So something like that?

```
long id = 222;    

Customer customer = customerRepository.findeOne(id);
Base base = baseRepository.findeOne(id);

boolean equals = customer.equals(((Customer) base));
```

And also would jpa be possible to do something like that?

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setStreet("space street 42");
address.setCountry("Trump Nation");

addressRepository.save(address);

Base base = baseRepository.findeOne(222);
base.setAddress(address);

baseRepository.save(base);
```

Will this work or isnt this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save an abstract entity because abstract entities aren't map to a database table. You need to save the child entity instead of the abstract one.